# Show 'Available in AppStore too' at upper end of page

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, mobile

From time to time, I do see on iOS devices web pages which have a region at the upper end of the page, which links to an app store. The text in the region reads like **'Available in AppStore too.'**.

Since all those regions share a common layout, I wonder if that's a software library or a service? Or does it is a feature of mobile Safari?

**Do we have libraries to promote the related app of a web-site if a user with a correct mobile device views the site?**

**Update 2014-06-29**

While Apple's Smart App Banners are great, only Safari 6+ will show them.

For [other iOS browsers and Android device this jQuery mobile plugin](https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner) might be of help: [jquery.smartbanner](https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner) at GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called 'Smart App Banners'.  All the needed details are available on the iOS Developer Library: [Promoting Apps with Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

Comment: Thank you! Work on device. In iOS simulator, the banner region appears, but stays empty.

Comment: Unfortunately, the jQuery Mobile Version of the site immediately overwrites the smart banner. Are you aware of a workaround?

Comment: I haven't used jQuery Mobile, but I found a [bug report](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6081) for this exact problem on Github.  Apparently jQuery Mobile auto-scrolls the page to hide the addressbar and this hides the banner too.  Try changing the setting `$.mobile.hideUrlBar` to false. The last comment in the bug report shows where to set this.

Comment: @ timclutton :: Thank you! Would you please post your answer here? I'm happy to accept it